# How can I subtract aggregated values from a timeseries in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I've got time-indexed data in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
              aapl   googl   msft
Date                         
2016-09-19  113.58  795.39  56.93
2016-09-20  113.57  799.78  56.81
2016-09-21  113.55  805.03  57.76
2016-09-22  114.62  815.95  57.82
2016-09-23  112.71  814.96  57.43
2016-09-26  112.88  802.65  56.90
2016-09-27  113.09  810.73  57.95
2016-09-28  113.95  810.06  58.03
2016-09-29  112.18  802.64  57.40
....
```

I'd like to compute an aggregate, and subtract that from each of these values.

```
monthly = df.resample('1m').mean()

                  aapl       googl       msft
Date                                         
2016-09-30  113.318000  806.125000  57.463000
2016-10-31  115.707143  813.651905  58.397619
2016-11-30  110.154286  784.736190  59.925238
2016-12-31  114.335714  800.624286  62.118095
...
```

How can I subtract these aggregates from the original values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to align these two DataFrames is to use `transform` instead of `agg`:

```
df - df.resample('1m').transform('mean')
```

will subtract the corresponding mean value from each point.